# how to find which jar containt special file using find command

Tags: java, shell

exec below shell

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar -tf {} \;|grep  "message_track.properties"
message_track.properties
message_track.properties
```

**it has two same file ,but which two jar containts the file.
how to find it ?**

Comment: searching it in IDE, e.g. eclipse.  is easier.

Comment: if third library jar ,you can't find using IDE

Comment: you can. Put it in cp, c-shift-r, write filename, then u will see. (Eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-print` to `find` so that the filenames are printed out and then use `egrep`:

```
$ find . -name "*.jar" -print -exec jar -tf {} \;|egrep  "jar$|message_track.properties"

./foo.jar
./bar.jar
message_track.properties
./baz.jar
message_track.properties
```

This shows that `bar.jar` and `baz.jar` contain the file.

You can even pipe this through another `grep`, assuming that this file occurs only once in each jar:

```
$ find . -name "*.jar" -print -exec jar -tf {} \;|egrep  "jar$|message_track.properties" | grep -B1 message_track.properties

./bar.jar
message_track.properties
./baz.jar
message_track.properties
```

If you want to go overboard, you can even use `awk` as follows:

```
$ find . -name "*.jar" -print -exec jar -tf {} \; | awk '{if($1~/jar$/)jar=$1;else if($1~/message_track/)arr[jar]=$1;}END{for(i in arr){print i " contains " arr[i]}}'

./bar.jar contains message_track.properties
./baz.jar contains message_track.properties
```

Comment: it means, if the name of the file contains `message_track`. You can change it to `message_track.properties` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

yet another way of doing this :

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec unzip -l {} \;|grep -E "Archive:|message_track.properties"
```